# TeeChart special abilities

Tags: .net, teechart

I have some questions about Teechart abilities, that i couldn't find in TeeChart Examples.

1) Is it posible to do a static X-axis with different scaled Y-axes,  that increase its maximal value  when the chart gets the right side of the window with scrolling visible part of current chart to left, with a scroll bar which allows to see history of charting. ( like it made in Welcome !\Chart styles\Standard\Line(Strip)\Realtime charting, but each line has its own axis( axes might have different scale ), X-axis scroll only when charts reaches its rightmost value by some fixed value, and having ability to remote chart to any previos interval of X (like a time window that moves through the time axis )).

2) If first is ok, is it possible to make a special label( like horizontal line with label on the chart) dinamicaly on the chart.

3) If i have a polyline or contour, can i  chage a point value by moving it throuhg a field? ( for example in case of interpolation, can i chage Y value by moving it by mouse right on chart at the given interpolation point). are there any special mesages that lets do this? Same question for control points of Bezier curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you can have multiple custom axes in a chart as explained in
   tutorial 4 and examples in the *All Features\Welcome !\Axes* section
   of the features demo. For the scrolling part you require I recommend
   the Scroll Pager tool demoed at *What's New?\Welcome !\New Chart
   Tools\ScrollPager Tool*. Both tutorials and features demo are
   available at TeeChart's program group.
2. I recommend using ColorLine tool combined with Annotation tool for
   this. An example can be found [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=6928&p=26848&hilit=ColorLine%20Annotation#p26848). Alternatively you can draw
   custom text in the chart canvas as in this example:

   ```
   public Form1()
   {
     InitializeComponent();
     InitializeChart();
   }

   private Steema.TeeChart.Tools.ColorLine colorLine1;

   private void InitializeChart()
   {
     tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;

     tChart1.Series.Add(new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.HorizBar()).FillSampleValues();

     colorLine1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Tools.ColorLine(tChart1.Chart);
     colorLine1.Axis = tChart1.Axes.Bottom;
     colorLine1.Value = tChart1[0].MinXValue() + (tChart1[0].MaxXValue() - tChart1[0].MinXValue()) / 2;

     tChart1.AfterDraw += tChart1_AfterDraw;
   }

   void tChart1_AfterDraw(object sender, Steema.TeeChart.Drawing.Graphics3D g)
   {
     string text = "My custom caption";
     SizeF size = g.MeasureString(g.Font, text);

     Rectangle rect = tChart1.Chart.ChartRect;
     int x = tChart1.Axes.Bottom.CalcPosValue(colorLine1.Value) - (int)size.Height;
     int y = rect.Top + (int)size.Width + 5;

     g.Font.Color = Color.Red;

     g.RotateLabel(x, y, text, 90);
   }
   ```
3. There's DragPoint tool for that. See the *All Features\Welcome
   !\Tools\Drag Point* example in the features demo. However, using
   this tool you'll be able to change the points in the source series,
   not calculated series. Polynomial, Contour and Bezier
   series/functions are calculated from a given source data. You won't
   be able to modify those calculated values directly, you'll have to
   modify source data series so they are recalculated.

Comment: Hello Narcis, thanks for your response/ I have another one question, what's the minimal version of TeeChart, that has ScrollPagerTool? unfortunately the latest version of .net i can use is .NET 2010, and i can't find this tool.

Comment: @user2519784 it was implemented in Build 4.1.2012.01030/1/2/3 from 3rd January 2012. You can check it at the version info page: http://www.steema.com/versioninfo/net

Comment: Thanks again, and one more question, abot second part of initial question. unfortunately, that's not exactly that i need, i need somethig like a caption on a colour line, so maybe there are some other ways?

Comment: and it would be greate, if this caption was verticaly orientated.

Comment: @user2519784 in that case you should manually draw it in the AfterDraw event using canvas' RotateLabel method. I'll update my reply containing an example of this.

Comment: @user2519784 you need to call Tools.Clear method, eg.: tChart1.Tools.Clear();

Comment: thanks, i've already found this method, and now i have another one question, now i have a realtime chart, that scrolls left for some fixed value every time when chart value is same to lefternmost value of curernet visible part of x-axis. And i also would like to know how can i make this thing: i would like to make a realtime chart, with fixed grid( it means that during the time and scroling the chart the grid doesn't move and only values on the x-axis changes, and the positions of this values are also fixed).

Comment: @user2519784 if I understand you correctly, that's what is shown in the All Features\Welcome !\Speed\Realtime charting example in the features demo. Some advice can also be found in the Real-time Charting article at http://www.teechart.net/reference/articles/index.php. It's a Delphi article but most of it can be applied to .NET as well. BTW, this discussion is getting away from the original subject, it might be better that you ask a new question if that's the case.

Comment: unfortunetely no, as you can see in All Features\Welcome !\Speed\Realtime charting that grid and x-axis moves left, and i want to make a static grid and position of the values, that changes in realtime( the value, not position on the " window " ). like combination of All Features\Welcome !\Speed\Realtime charting and an example on the All Features\Welcome ! on the bottom of the window( as tou can see the frid is ststic ).

Comment: @user2519784 is something like the All Features\Welcome !\Chart styles\Standard\Fast Line\Fast Delete and Fast Pen example what you are looking for?

Comment: Exactly, with scroLLPoints = 0. and i want to have a history, and having ability to scrol chart to some interval using standart tool.

Comment: @user2519784 use Axis.Bottom.SetMinMax without deleting series points then.

Comment: I tried to do this, but that does not work, i have the same situation to real time charting in example, the axis and grid are moving left. on the next coment i added a code, but this code makes the grid and axis move.

Comment: private void timer1_Tick(object Sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            maxPoints = tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Maximum - tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Minimum;
            if (realtimeLine.XValues.Last == tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Maximum  )
                tChart1.Axes.Bottom.SetMinMax(realtimeLine.XValues.Last - maxPoints+1, realtimeLine.XValues.Last +1);

            realtimeLine.Add(t++, rnd.Next());
            
            tChart1.AutoRepaint = true;
            tChart1.Refresh();
        }

Comment: in other words, i want to change labels on the axis, for example, now i have 0___5___10___15...__50, at next tick i want to have 1___6___11___16...___51, in this this case chart redraws but the labels on the axis are at the same place, and grid is drown at this points.

Comment: @user2519784 yes, that's what the Fast Delete and Fast Pen example does. Have you looked at the demo/example code?

Comment: yes. i did the same thing since your first responce. i found that if i chage a step of a labels it's easily to do, for example, now initialy i have tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Maximum = 20;
            tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Minimum = 0; in this case if step is 1, everything is fine, but as soon as values come to 1000 everything fails, so how can i manualy set the step of the labels on the axis?

Comment: @user2519784 using Axis.Increment property. For more info about axis setting see tutorial 4.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help,  probbly i gave  not very proper explanation, actually i nedded this:  tChart1.Axes.Bottom.SetMinMax(realtimeLine.XValues.Last - maxPoints + 1, realtimeLine.XValues.Last + 1);
                        tChart1.Axes.Bottom.IncrementOffset = (int)tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Increment - (int)realtimeLine.XValues.Last % (int)tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Increment;

Comment: I have another question. it's not connected to this topic, but i don't know why, but stacloverflow doesn't let me post it. I am trying to change a grid settings in teechat for .NET. I have changed some grid property, and now i have a grid drawn in the way i don't like. I need a vertical grid lines, that drawn at labels on the x-axis. now i have a vertical lines, that are drawn at the not labeled points on the axis. what should i do to change it, and how can i get axes to grid settings?

Comment: @user2519784 see StackOverflow's help section on question bans: http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans. Is this the error message you get? Regarding your question, are axis labels regular and according to Increment and ticks settings? That's what's needed to get grid lines on labels.

Comment: thanks  for response, not it was connected with incorrect style of a question. I've already resolved this using java tutorial on steema.com, i've found that there was no reaction on tchart editor on the field centered, when i unchecked it( probably it's a bug? ), so i manualy changed this property to false.